# How to fix 'Ajax form submission' with PHP

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

The code shown below employs the Ajax but there is an indefinite loading bar as if the function never gets called from the controller. How would I go about getting the HTML to successfully initiate this function?

```
//HTML
<button type="button" data-url="/ajax/controller.php" name="dosubmit" class="wojo button positive">Approve</button>
<input name="ProcessApproval" type="hidden" value="1">
```

```
//Function
public function ProcessPOApproval()
      {    
        $PID = $_GET['pid'];

        $ApprovalTransactionalData = array(
            'PONum' => "$PID",
            'Step' => "4"
        );
        self::$db->insert("accounting_transact", $ApprovalTransactionalData);
}
```

```
//Controller
<?php
 /* == Proccess Project File == */
 if (isset($_POST['ProcessApproval'])):
    if (intval($_POST['ProcessApproval']) == 0 || empty($_POST['ProcessApproval'])):
        die();
    endif;
    ProcessPOApproval();
endif;
?>
```

```
     //Ajax
       /* == Master Form == */
       $('body').on('click', 'button[name=dosubmit]', function() {
           posturl = $(this).data('url')

           function showResponse(json) {
               if (json.status == "success") {
                   $(".wojo.form").removeClass("loading").slideUp();
                   $("#msgholder").html(json.message);
               } else {
                   $(".wojo.form").removeClass("loading");
                   $("#msgholder").html(json.message);
               }
           }

           function showLoader() {
               $(".wojo.form").addClass("loading");
           }
           var options = {
               target: "#msgholder",
               beforeSubmit: showLoader,
               success: showResponse,
               type: "post",
               url: SITEURL + posturl,
               dataType: 'json'
           };

           $('#wojo_form').ajaxForm(options).submit();
       });
```

Below is the HTML with the wojo_form id as requested.

```
    <form id="wojo_form" name="wojo_form" method="post">
    <div class="three fields">
      <div class="field">
        <label>Submitting Accountant</label>
        <label class="input"><i class="icon-prepend icon calendar"></i>
          <input type="text" value="" disabled="disabled" name="created">
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="field">
        <label>Next Approval</label>
        <label class="input"><i class="icon-append icon calendar"></i>
          <input type="text" value="<?php echo $row->lastlogin;?>" disabled="disabled" name="lastlogin">
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="field">
        <label>Approval Group</label>
        <label class="input"><i class="icon-prepend icon laptop"></i>
          <input type="text" value="<?php echo $row->lastip;?>" disabled="disabled" name="lastip">
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="wojo double fitted divider"></div>
    <button type="button" data-url="/ajax/controller.php" action="" name="dosubmit" class="wojo button">Decline Approval</button>
    <input name="ProcessDecline" type="hidden" value="1">
    <button type="button" data-url="ajax/controller.php" name="dosubmit" class="wojo button positive">Approve</button>
    <input name="ProcessApproval" type="hidden" value="1">
    <button type="button" data-url="/ajax/controller.php" name="dosubmit" class="wojo button info">Add Notes</button>
    <input name="ProcessNotes" type="hidden" value="1">
  </form>
```

If you need anything additional please let me know.

Comment: `$_GET['pid']` requires `?get=###` in `data-url`.

Comment: `dataType: 'json'` means that the controller has to echo JSON. The controller doesn't return anything.

Comment: @Barmar you probably meant ?pid=### right ? also notice that the OP is setting ajax as `type: "post"` so AFAIU $_GET would be empty.

Comment: @NelsonTeixeira Right, I meant `?pid=XXX`. `$_GET` is still set from URL parameters even in POST requests.

Comment: @JamesCarlin can you post the HTML correpondent to #wojo_form  ? if the fields above aren't childs of this form, they're simply not sent to the controller. Or else you have to include the parameters in the post url as Barmer said.

Comment: @Barmar didn't know that. Thanks.

Comment: Do you have an error in your js console? I would have thought  posturl = $(this).data('url') would need a semi-colon at the end, this might be causing the function not to run?

Comment: @NelsonTeixeira I modified the post to add the full HTML with the wojo ID

Comment: Additionally, I am getting "POST http://localhost/ajax/controller.php 500 (Internal Server Error)" in the console